# How to replicate a cygwin install and environment on another machine?

Tags: cygwin

I have my machine setup to run cmake and gcc, and I would like to install the cygwin with the exact same set of packages and parameters on the build machine, and possibly on other development machine.  Is there a way to do that without having to setup cygwin manually in the GUI, using the Setup.exe as provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Cygwin's setup.exe [command line options](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.setup.html#faq.setup.cli) to automate the process.

For an automated installation, the Cygwin website [recommends](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.setup.html#faq.setup.automated) doing a full install and saving off the downloaded package tree, then performing a local install using the following command:

```
setup.exe -q -L -l {path-to-package-dir}
```

That's only one possible setup, however; depending on exactly what you want to do, the command line options allow you to download fresh packages from the internet, install specific packages, etc etc.

Comment: FYI: There are a few stages along the way when the installer is doing some work but not updating the progress bar, and appears unresponsive to Windows. Be patient.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, following the Cygwin doc will result in downloading the entire distribution but installing only the "default" system. The steps below, in contrast, download and install exactly what is desired.

1. On one machine, run `setup.exe` and choose `Install from Internet`. Pick a mirror, then pick the exact combination of packages you want.

   - Note the location where you copied your local packages, e.g. `\\myserver\myDir`.
   - You can repeat step 1 more than once if you forgot to add something.
   - Wait for the install to complete. Some metadata will be produced during the install.
2. On the other machines, run `setup.exe` and choose `Install from Local Directory` or use the command-line recipe from `me_and` above. Provide the location where you cached the install (`\\myserver\myDir`). You can also copy the entire cache onto an SD card or CD.

   - Go get some coffee. The installer will seem to hang for several minutes after processing all the downloads. Don't worry about it, be patient. Eventually the package selector will appear.
3. This is the crucial step. Go to the top of the package tree and select `All`. This will install all the packages that have previously been downloaded onto `\\myserver\myDir`.

It would be nice to have a command line argument for step 3 (selecting install all packages) so the entire step could be automated. I couldn't find one. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Thanks, not selecting all may have been my issue. I'm gonna get some coffee and I'll try it today.

Comment: Awesome thanks. It was this simple. Wish I could upvote twice.